# How to get a list of users who can log in to jenkins via API

Tags: jenkins

This is similar to [how to get all the jenkins users through api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557181/how-to-get-all-the-jenkins-users-through-api), but that provides the list of ALL users, not the users who can actually log in to Jenkins, which is listed under https://[JENKINS]/securityRealm/.

How do you get the list of users that can login to jenkins via an API call?
In other words, how do you get the list of users under https://[JENKINS]/securityRealm/ via an API call?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need this via the web API or from a Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Ideally web API but if worse comes to worse I can make it work with a Jenkins file via a groovy script. In fact I can make it work with any sort of thing I can automate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class [`HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm`](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/security/HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm.html) has a method `getAllUsers()` which is documented as

> All users who can login to the system.

Groovy code sample:

```groovy
Hudson.instance.getSecurityRealm().getAllUsers().each { 
    println it 
}
```